# How to show data dynamically in laravel using jquery without page reload

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want to fetch data from database without reloading page. I am working with laravel. I have fetched those data using jquery. 
Here is my jquery code.

```
 function loadData() {
var id=$('#projectId').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/teammessage/'+id,
      success: function(value){
        console.log(value);
        $(value.success).each(function(e,k){
       $('#test').append(value.success[e].team_message);
        });
      }
    });
    }
```

Now I want to show that data without page reload if any new data inserted into the database. 
I called this `loadData()` function in `setInterval`function like this one.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  loadData();
}, 1000);
```

But this `setInterval` function keep previous data and load data again. I want to show just updated data. Like, if in my view have `A`, `B` and new `C` is inserted into database by other user. It should show `A`, `B`, `C` without reloading page.

Comment: You need to use socket in your laravel.

Comment: `$('#test').empty().append(...)`?

Comment: Get count of existing records first, then call the ajax. check whether you have new records by counting new records. If does only add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by using just `load` method. Like this one.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
var id=$('#projectId').val();
$( "#team-messageid" ).load( "/teammessage/"+id);
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function loadData() {
var id=$('#projectId').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/teammessage/'+id,
      success: function(value){
        console.log(value);
        $(value.success).each(function(e,k){
       $('#test').html(value.success[e].team_message);
        });
      }
    });
    }
```

if you get all data from jquery then just replace it